# Navigation Bar Buttons disappear after returning from a push view

Tags: ios, xcode

I have 4 buttons on the top bar setup using array of buttons with leftBarButtonItems and rightBarButtonItems. When I push to another view and return the buttons are gone. The area where the buttons should be located are not active (cannot select). If I put the application in the background and bring it back to the foreground the buttons are restored.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Here is the code that initializes the buttons:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIBarButtonItem *selectButton          = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(selectPlayers:)];
    UIBarButtonItem *manageButton          = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Manage" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(managePlayers:)];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems =
    [NSArray arrayWithObjects:manageButton, selectButton, nil];

    UIBarButtonItem *TeamsButton          = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Teams" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(CreateTeams:)];

    UIBarButtonItem *TransferButton          = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Transfer" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(Transfer:)];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems =
    [NSArray arrayWithObjects:TeamsButton,TransferButton, nil];

}
```

I found a workaround. The problem view has the status bar hidden. The pushed view shows the status bar. If I also hide the status bar on the pushed view the buttons no longer disappear. This looks like a bug in xcode or IOS.

Comment: Agreed code would be helpful. If you're manipulating the buttons in viewWillDisappear, viewDidDisappear, viewWillAppear, or viewDidAppear you can run into these type of odd states.